# .NET Framework 4 installFailed

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, 64-bit, windows-installer, excel-addins

My addin target 64 bit Excel requires .NET 4 client profile. When I build installer (VS Setup project), I put .NET 4 client profile in prerequisite.
When I install my AddIn on a PC without .NET framework 4 client profile, my installer tries to download & install it.

However, the installation failed.  I have admin right so no permission issue.  IT guys told me there is some certificate issue with .NET 4 web installer and I have to use Full installer.

Then I replaced .NET 4 client profile with .NET 4 in prerequisite.  But it did not work either. Installer gave the almost the same error.

But if I download .NET 4 installation and install it manually before install my addin, it installs without problem.

Here is error message: (with .NET 4 client profile in prerequisite)
....

> Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile
>   (x86 and x64)', phase BeforePackage Reading value 'Version' of
>   registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework
>   Setup\NDP\v4\Client' Unable to read registry value Not setting value
>   for property 'DotNet40Client_TargetVersion' The following properties
>   have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile
>   (x86 and x64)': Running checks for command
>   'DotNetFX40Client\dotNetFx40_Client_setup.exe' Result of running
>   operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value
>   'HomeSite': false Skipping ByPassIf because Property
>   'DotNet40Client_TargetVersion' was not defined Result of running
>   operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'AdminUser' and value 'false':
>   false Result of running operator 'VersionLessThan' on property
>   'VersionNT' and value '5.1.2': false Result of running operator
>   'ValueEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'IA64':
>   false Result of checks for command
>   'DotNetFX40Client\dotNetFx40_Client_setup.exe' is 'Install' 'Microsoft
>   .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result:
>   Install Needed Verifying file integrity of
>   C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD54E2.tmp\DotNetFX40Client\dotNetFx40_Client_setup.exe
>   WinVerifyTrust returned 0 File trusted Installing using command
>   'C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD54E2.tmp\DotNetFX40Client\dotNetFx40_Client_setup.exe'
>   and parameters ' /q /norestart /ChainingPackage ClientX64ClickOnce
>   /lcid 1033' Process exited with code -2146762482 Status of package
>   'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64)' after
>   install is 'InstallFailed'

Edit:
I change .NET Framework 4 client profile to .NET framework 4,  installer still failed but I got a slightly different error message.

> Component Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64) has failed to
>   install with the following error message: "A failure occurred
>   attempting to install the .NET Framework 4 Full."
>
> The following components failed to install:
>   - Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)
>
> See the setup log file located at
>   'C:\Users***\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD2403.tmp\install.log' for more
>   information.
>
> the log file is:  File trusted Running checks for package 'Microsoft
>   .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)', phase BeforePackage Reading value
>   'Version' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework
>   Setup\NDP\v4\Full' Unable to read registry value Not setting value for
>   property 'DotNet40Full_TargetVersion' The following properties have
>   been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)':
>   Running checks for command 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe'
>   Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode'
>   and value 'HomeSite': false Skipping ByPassIf because Property
>   'DotNet40Full_TargetVersion' was not defined Result of running
>   operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'AdminUser' and value 'false':
>   false Result of running operator 'VersionLessThan' on property
>   'VersionNT' and value '5.1.2': false Result of running operator
>   'ValueEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'IA64':
>   false Result of checks for command
>   'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe' is 'Install' 'Microsoft .NET
>   Framework 4 (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: Install Needed Verifying
>   file integrity of
>   C:\Users\yhou\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD2403.tmp\DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe
>   WinVerifyTrust returned 0 File trusted Installing using command
>   'C:\Users\yhou\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD2403.tmp\DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe'
>   and parameters ' /q /norestart /ChainingPackage FullX64Bootstrapper
>   /lcid 1033' Process exited with code -2146762482 Status of package
>   'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)' after install is
>   'InstallFailed'

Comment: No, it is a problem with their machines.  Ask them when they last had Windows Update turned on.  The migration from 1024 to 2048 keys that's going on is a likely failure cause.  Have them install .NET 4 themselves to avoid getting caught in this.

Comment: thanks. This is a VM image. We could ask client to Install .NET 4 first but that's not ideal we want to install necessary components together with addin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed registry key value State to 0x23c00, worked perfectly!!!

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WinTrust\Trust Providers\Software Publishing
    State    REG_DWORD    0x23c00
```

For more info see 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproperf/thread/c273df3c-cdb9-4572-989f-446b4b390b24/

Comment: Though the workaround works, I want to say I do not like it, really do not want to touch registry

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue in the past. I changed the requirement from Framework 4 Client to Framework 4 and it fixed the issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just tried http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/net-framework-4-fails-installation-with-generic/f93cd039-0e3d-4453-8db8-130ac9a5051a?tab=AllReplies#tabs, does not work, either